# How do I mock a method in test code that's been "declare"d in production code?

Tags: mocking, typescript

In my production code, I have a couple of lines of code that's declaring two functions for use with Google Analytics:

```
declare function ga(command: string, type: string, exceptionDetails: Object);
declare function ga(command: string, type: string, category: string, action: string, label: string)
```

In my unit test code, I would like to implement a mock of these functions so that it does nothing. However, my app.tests.ts references app.ts, so I cannot simply do something like

```
var ga = (command: string, type: string, exceptionDetails: Object) => { };
```

because that is a duplicate definition.

How can I achieve this without adding the ga definition to my unit test runner html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could override the function by substituting its value. You are *almost* doing this in your example, but because you have put `var` in front of it, it looks like accidental duplication.

Remove the `var` and just have:

```
ga = (command: string, type: string, exceptionDetails: Object) => { };
```

Simplified example for illustration:

```
var ga = (command: string, type: string, exceptionDetails: Object) => { alert('hi'); };

// ...

ga = (command: string, type: string, exceptionDetails: Object) => { alert('overridden'); };


// Alerts "overridden"
ga('a', 'b', {});
```

Comment: I'll try this out and post an update/resolution. If this works I'm going to feel dumb :P